# Why "which train goes to" not which train does go to

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, do-support, emphatic-polarity

One day,  I was teaching this kid English.  We were talking about using "which" in different sentences.
Then It came to using **which** with Inanimate objects and while we were discussing about it,  he asked me why can't we can't form a question like this:

> "**Which train does go to Boston**

Not being able to answer the question, I just put it off which I didn't want to.

Now I feel bad  and don't want to leave any bad impression. 
 I know this is how such questions are formed but I am not aware why we can not add **auxiliary verb Does**

So why we never ask such questions this way?

Comment: _Does_ can be used to emphasise another verb. You wouldn't start a conversation by asking "Which train does go to Boston?", but if you were told that the one you had been about to board doesn't go there, you might ask "So which train _does_ go there?"

Answer (score 1):

*Do* support is required in questions where the verb and the subject are inverted, so

> (archaic) See you that?

is replaced in modern English by

> Do you see that?

Where the question word is the subject, it does not invert, so no *do* support is required:

> Who said that?
>
> Which train goes to Boston?

As in affirmative sentences, *do* is possible, but is either emphatic or contrastive.

So *Which train **does** go to Boston?* might occur after a discussion like

> That train goes to Boston, doesn't it?
>
> No, that one goes to Lincoln.
>
> Well, which train does go to Boston?